# How to pass a variable by value to another thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust, closures, borrow-checker, pass-by-value

I need to launch multiple threads in Rust, where each thread receives its worker id (integer between 0 and 31 inclusively). How to do it in Rust?

Here's what I have tried:

```
struct PtrWrapper(*const u8);

unsafe impl Sync for PtrWrapper {}
unsafe impl Send for PtrWrapper {}

// ...

let data = &mmap[begin_offset..end_offset];

let n_workers = 32;
let total_bytes = data.len();
let bytes_per_worker = (total_bytes + n_workers - 1) / n_workers;
let page_size = 512;
let data_ptr = PtrWrapper(data.as_ptr());
if bytes_per_worker >= page_size {
    thread::scope(|scope| {
        for i in 0..n_workers {
            scope.spawn(|| {
                let _ = &data_ptr;
                let i_first = bytes_per_worker * i;
                let i_limit = cmp::min(total_bytes, bytes_per_worker * (i+1));
                for j in (i_first..i_limit).step_by(page_size) {
                    unsafe {
                        std::ptr::read_volatile(data_ptr.0.offset(j.try_into().unwrap()));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This gives a compilation error:

```
  error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `i`, which is owned by the current function
     --> src/lib.rs:477:41
      |
  475 |                     thread::scope(|scope| {
      |                                    ----- has type `&'1 Scope<'1, '_>`
  476 |                         for i in 0..n_workers {
  477 |                             scope.spawn(|| {
      |                                         ^^ may outlive borrowed value `i`
  478 |                                 let _ = &data_ptr;
  479 |                                 let i_first = bytes_per_worker * i;
      |                                                                  - `i` is borrowed here
      |
  note: function requires argument type to outlive `'1`
     --> src/lib.rs:477:29
      |
  477 | / ...                   scope.spawn(|| {
  478 | | ...                       let _ = &data_ptr;
  479 | | ...                       let i_first = bytes_per_worker * i;
  480 | | ...                       let i_limit = cmp::min(total_bytes, bytes_per_worker * (i+1));
  ...   |
  485 | | ...                       }
  486 | | ...                   });
      | |________________________^
  help: to force the closure to take ownership of `i` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
      |
  477 |                             scope.spawn(move || {
      |                                         ++++
  
  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0373`.
  error: could not compile `safetensors-python` due to previous error
```

I moved the other variables outside the scope, so that Rust knows that references to them will outlive the threads. However, what can I do with `i` variable?

Comment: Have you tried the compiler's suggestion and added `move` in front of the closure you pass to `scope.spawn`?

Comment: @JonasFassbender, `move` seems to break everything else because it removes the values from the outer scope, as far as I understand. I have tried it, of course.

Comment: `move` implicitly copies values that implement `Copy`, which includes references. Correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAICT `PointerWrapper` and therefore `data_ptr` is the only type not implementing `Copy` that is captured by your closure. If `data_ptr` would be a reference, maybe `move` would work?

Comment: @SergeRogatch `move` means the new thread takes ownership of every value the closure closes over (ether copies `Copy` types or moves `Move` types), this is usually necessary for `spawn` as the threads are non-scoped and (as far as the type system is concerned) can outlive their creator. Usually the solution is to use `Arc` around types which need to be shared between multiple threads, and move a clone of the arc into each thread.

Comment: I've got to say `PtrWrapper` looks dodgy as all hell though, you've got a bunch of workers doing unsynchronised reads from a memory map without a care in the world (also `let _ = &data_ptr;` literally doesn't do anything).

Answer (score 1):

Just adding `move` probably did not work for you because the only proper use of `data_ptr` inside of the closure is `data_ptr.0` the compiler is 'smart' enough to only try to move that part into the closure, that results in it trying to move a bare `*const u8` which is not allowed because pointers don't implement `Send` nor `Sync`, you can fix it by taking a reference to `data_ptr` ahead of time and adding `move` to the closure:

```rust
// …
let data_ptr = PtrWrapper(data.as_ptr());
let data_ptr = &data_ptr;
if bytes_per_worker >= page_size {
    std::thread::scope(|scope| {
        for i in 0..n_workers {
            scope.spawn(move || {
                let i_first = bytes_per_worker * i;
                let i_limit = total_bytes.min(bytes_per_worker * (i+1));
                for j in (i_first..i_limit).step_by(page_size) {
                    unsafe {
                        std::ptr::read_volatile(data_ptr.0.offset(j.try_into().unwrap()));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```